# laravel get data when give id not match with join table id

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

here is my category table data

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 6 |
| 7 |

when in my post bale I join with this `category table`

here is my post table sample data

1. ID = 1,
2. name = 'hellow'
3. category id = 4 (i join with category table but selected category is
   deleted)

here is my index SQL query  (when categy_id match with the category.id) then only its fetch

```
$post = DB::table('posts)->join('category','posts.category_id','categories.id')-.paginate(10);
```

for some reason, the selected category can be deleted so I try to get category deleted post data

here is my query

```
$cpost = DB::table('posts')->join('categories','posts.category_id', '!=' ,'categories.id')->select('post.*')->paginate(5);
```

but above query duplicate post data based on available category data

i want all post data which are category id is not matched with in category table id how can i get that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Key is the `leftJoin` instead of default `innerJoin` (`join`).

```php
        // posts without assigned or existing category
        $posts = \DB::table('posts')
            ->leftJoin('category','posts.category_id','categories.id')
            ->whereNull('categories.id')
            ->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 1):

why are you doing a join for this? you already have category id stored in your post table.

```
$cpost = DB::table('posts')->where('category_id','!=', $category_id)->paginate(5);
```

Comment: still same ([1,2,6,7]) not match with 4 so record duplicated 4 times

Answer (score 1):

Just try it:

```
$cpost = DB::table('posts')
->join('categories','posts.category_id', '=' ,'categories.id')
->select('post.*', 'categories.*')
->whereNotIn('posts.category_id', DB::raw('select id from categories'))
->paginate(5);
```

Comment: error on this line >whereNotIn('categories.id', DB::raw('select id from categories'))

Comment: ->whereNotIn('posts.category_id', DB::raw('select id from categories'))